# One new column gets added when i use model.matrix on a column that has factors

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

One column x4 in my data set has characters A,B,C. I want to use this model.matrix function on this data set. So i coerce the column that has characters into a factor column.

```
mydata1$x4 = factor(mydata1$x4,labels = c("1","2","3"))
x=model.matrix(y~.,data=mydata1)[,-1]
```

But when i use the model.matrix function the output has five columns. The column x4 from the existing data set got split into x42 and x43 columns. Where have i gone wrong? I get the output as shown below.

[image: Output]

Comment: This is the intended behavior. Column `x4` has been dummy-coded ([explanation](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/dummy.htm)). So now the question is: What did you expect to see?

Comment: Would the addition of dummy column affect the output in any way?

Comment: I expected to see just one column with A as 1,B as 2, C as 3

Comment: @Dixon it's unclear what you are trying to do here, do you want to convert your `character` column to `numeric`?

Comment: Ok, let me get this clear. Your original column `x4` contains `A`, `B` and `C`. All you want is that that column contains `1`, `2`, `3`, respectively.. correct? Well, that's what you achieve with your first line of code, right? Before running any code, `head(mydata1$x4)` returns `"B" "B" "B" "A" "C" "C"`; after running the first line of code, it should return `2 2 2 1 3 3`. To me, this seems like what you are trying to get. I am not exactly sure why you are using `model.matrix` here and it kind of suggests that you are trying to do something else as well, but I don't understand what.

Comment: I am trying to use the glmnet function on the data set. since the data set contains characters, i thought i had to convert those characters to factors for the glmnet function. Thats the reason i used the factor function and to make the data set compatible to the glmnet function i used the matrix.model function. I am new to R so facing some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `mode.matrix` you column with `Factor data type` split into separate columns.
so you can change your x4 column data type to number type to prevents of splitting

```
mydata1$x4 <- as.numeric(mydata1$x4)
```